# Angular 5 common.js: 263 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ st is not defined

Tags: angular

My Angular 5 project is working fine and all of a sudden, i'm getting:
Angular 5 common.js: 263 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ st is not defined

however project works fine but still see this error in console.

can someone help me to solve this error ?

here is my package.json file:

```
dependencies: {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.4.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "4.13.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.1.0",
    "moment-mini-ts": "2.20.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-cookie": "1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

Comment: can you please share the code in stackblitz to replicate this, just with the dependencies list we cant identify what the issue is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have the same in an Angular 6 app, but common.js is actually part of some chrome extension, not the Angular app.  It's part of the StandsApp ad blocker:  https://www.standsapp.org/

Comment: Wow that's a good catch. Do you know why the issue is there? I have the same problem in a React app, just wondering how to get rid of it. No big deal I guess

Comment: The error has been there for a while and they haven't fixed it yet.  I did report it to them and they are aware of it.  I guess it's time to use a different ad blocker.

Answer (score 2):

It's like what Jonesie said, i have other node.js app and it showing

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $st is not defined at common.js:263"

. If you want the error message go away, just turn of the extension.